# openvpn access to a corporate network

Tags: openvpn

I have configured openvpn to access remotely to my network and it seems to work. But I cant do the following:

I access only to the server but I want to access to the entire corporate network
I can not surf the internet while I'm connected.
Can anyone help me?
Thank you

This is the server.conf configuration file

```
port 1194
proto udp
dev tun
ca ca.crt
cert server.crt
key server.key
dh dh.pem
server 192.168.200.0 255.255.255.0
push "redirect-gateway def1"
push "dhcp-option DNS 8.8.8.8"
push "dhcp-option DNS 8.8.4.4"
duplicate-cn
keepalive 20 60
comp-lzo
persist-key
persist-tun
daemon
log-append /var/log/myvpn/openvpn.log
verb 4
```

Comment: Redirecting gateway is a silly idea: this makes *all* client's traffic go through the VPN. What you want instead is 1) pushing a route or a set of routes to your corporate LAN to the client" 2) making sure the openvpn server has a set of `iroute` directive to route between its private network and the corporate LAN network(s).

Comment: And yes, as Igor mentioned, you need IP forwarding enabled both in the kernel and in your firewall (netfilter / iptables) setup.

Answer (score 0):

On server:

```
iptables -A POSTROUTING -t nat -j MASQUERADE
echo 1 >/proc/sys/net/ipv4/ip_forward
```